# facebook Enhanced Auth Dialog but want to display a message to the user before

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I am trying to use new enhanced auth dialog instead of old one in a new application,
I want to first of all display a page with a message to the user, then he can click on a button and then he have the enhanced auth dialog.

My worries are when i set up my new application, the auth dialog v2 is displayed and then if the user accept permissions, then he is redirected to my home.php.
Is it possible to use enhanced auth dialog but first of all displaying a page which inform about the application?

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have found the answer.

If you don't want that Facebook display the enhanced auth dialog before your application, but do it manually, when you want,
in your app settings, in "auth dialog"  tab, don't write anyting in "Authenticated Referrals" !

And that's all :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to first display a page to the user before putting up the auth dialog.  I have a current production app that does just that.

1. In your app, have a connect button of your own making that you display to the user when they are not connected to Facebook.
2. When a user clicks it, redirect to the page you want to show them with the special wording.
3. On that special page, have the real facebook login button (or a button/link that fires off FB.login())

Comment: yes, I've done it with the old one and the new one.  As it is not important to the workflow, either one can be linked to in at the end of step 3.

Comment: Can you send me the application's URL in order to just see the flow?

Comment: It is for a purchased app and there is no demo mode.